EF Core junction table seeding issue
In my app I am using EF Core.
I have a many to many relationship between machine and option
Every machine has a different price per option, so I added price as payload to the junction table.
Here's my (pseudo) code - Machine class:
List<OptionMachine> options; // Only holding OptionMachine list and not of options because we only want to access the options with a price.
String description;

Option:
List<Machine> machines;

OptionMachine:
public int MachineId { get; set; } = default!;

private Machine machine = default!;
public required Machine Machine
{
    get => machine;
    set => machine = value ?? throw new ArgumentNullException();
}

public int OptionId { get; set; } = default!;

private Option Option = default!;
public required = Option Option
{
    get => customOption;
    set => customOption = value ?? throw new ArgumentNullException();
}

private decimal price = default!;

public required decimal Price { get; set; }

Now my question is how do I seed Machine?
Lets say I have some existing options:
var options = await dbContext.Options.ToListAsync();

// Machine to seed:
Machine machine = new()
                  {
                      description = "MyTestMachine",
                      options = { new() 
                                  { 
                                      Machine = // how to reference machine here?, 
                                      Option = options[0], 
                                      price = 500M 
                                  }
                                }
                  }

As you can see I cannot use the machine itself to seed the junction table, how do I go about doing this?
I know I can probably add them later, outside of the initialization but I'd like to enforce that a machine needs to exist WITH options WITH a price.

What is your goal of enforcing that particular way of initialization? Protecting your code from users, from other developers or from yourself? Whoever it is, your desired initialization wont help either way. I think you need to clarify/add details to your question

Myself and other developers. What more details do you need?

In that case I'd suggest using the constructor of Machine, add OptionsMachine as a parameter and initialize everything from there since you can just use 'this' to set your Machine-reference in OptionsMachine

Gotcha, that is a valid and good approach, I think that will do thanks

NB: EF Core doesn't require you to set the property; since you're adding the OptionMachine to a Machine's options collection, EF will automatically "fix up" the relationship for you. The reason you're struggling is that the Machine property is marked as required, so you have to set it to something; and it throws an exception if you set it to null.

@RichardDeeming Gotcha but then I would need a seperate list of options in my machine class right? Or not? Could you please provide an example if possible?

@RoseannePeeters If you remove the required modifier from the Machine property, you could just omit the property: Machine machine = new() { description = "...", options = [new() { Option = options[0], price = 500M }] };

Oooh great, will try both solutions thanks! EF Core really is smart.
